# Use Pyembroidery to Convert Vector File to .DST embroidery file

Tags: python, svg, vector, printing, dst-embroidery

I am looking into a solution to automate turning vector files (.svg) into .dst embroidery files. I have been looking at pyembroidery and was wondering if this is even possible before I dive in trying. The files would be just text to start to keep it simple.

Comment: Did you find a complete solution?

Answer (score 4):

Bonafides: Author of pyembroidery, author of svgelements.

Yes and no. Yeah, you can take normal vector files and turn the vector directions easily into embroidery. So you get an svg path and you can turn that stroke into a dst. And you can do that in just a couple lines. Here are those lines:

```
import glob

from pyembroidery import *
from svgelements import *

for svg_file in glob.glob("*.svg"):
    pattern = EmbPattern()
    for element in SVG.parse(svg_file, transform="scale(%f)" % (254.0 / 96.0)):
        if isinstance(element, Shape):
            element = Path(element)
        if isinstance(element, Path):
            for subpath in element.as_subpaths():
                subpath = Path(subpath)
                distance = subpath.length(error=1e7, min_depth=4)
                segments = int(distance / 20.0)
                points = [subpath.point(i / float(segments)) for i in range(int(segments)+1)]
                points = [(p.x, p.y) for p in points]
                pattern.add_block(points, subpath.stroke)
    PyEmbroidery.write(pattern, svg_file + ".dst")
```

This will load up all the svg files in the current directory and turn them into dst files.  The svg library is another project I wrote also on pypi. It's likely the best svg code on python. Some of the shorthand there is a bit related to svg.path and some might seem kinda magical but the library allows multiplication by svg transform strings. The (254.0 / 96.0) bit is because natively path units are typically, in modern svgs 96 pixels per inch, and the native resolution of dst files is 0.1 mm per unit. So the transform there makes the units perfectly equal.

Now for the 'No' part of the answer. The fill conversion is actually a bit more difficult. There's two algorithms to perform the main flood fill, the hard one is tatsumi and requires a bunch of adjustments for merge and split nodes and to graph out the shape into sweepable geometry and some extra stuff that is a bit screwy. The easier one is Eulerian fill which requires turning the filled shape into a Eulerian graph and removing some bits of the edge. It's actually within the realm of performable code. It's the code that underlays InkStitch which is the main inkscape addon embroidery program today. Which is what pyembroidery was written serve as the backend I/O stuff, before I got perma-banned by the author for constructive criticism.

If you just want the strokes. Done. Take that to the bank. If you want the fills the math gets harder than a simple Embroidery/IO module will readily do for you.

[image: original svg file]
[image: converted dst, rendered in Wilcom]

Comment: Any new recommendations for a full solution since answering in 2020?  I found pyembroidery and then this answer, you were onto something special as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Programming_Learner_DK The full solution is generally to implement the Eulerian fill algorithm, there's an example in `vpype-embroidery` which I wrote as an addon for some plotting software. It, at least, does the basic needed part of allowing embroidery fills (which minimize line overlapping and cuts).